# alfresco model deploy not working after first deploy

Tags: caching, alfresco, activiti

I have a workflowModel-custom.xml file which I defined a workflow model in it.
I used

```
http://localhost:4080/alfresco/faces/jsp/admin/repoadmin-console.jsp
```

to deploy model;

```
deploy model alfresco/workflow/workflowModel-custom.xml
```

First time it worked good but after first time it seems that my changes didn't have effect on deployment until I restarted my tomcat.
Does alfresco have some cache to save files and if yes how to disable it?

Comment: Also, when asking Alfresco questions, it's always good to include your alfresco version.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to consider. Lets' say you deployed your workflow version 1.0

- Current workflow instances.

Any workflow instance that you deployed will be version 1.0.

So when you deploy a new workflow version, all the old instances will still use the old version.

- Redeploying a workflow.

When you want to deploy a new version, you have to set a "redeploy" flag (or redeploy in workflow console.).

- Undeploy a workflow

You could do something else here: undeploy the workflow model. If you do, all running instances will be terminated.

Read more about workflows [here](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/WorkflowAdministration#Redeploying_a_Process_Definition) and [here](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Workflow_Console).